# How do I create fixtures for ActiveStorage variants for Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, rails-activestorage

### Summary

On a personal project, I have a view that references an ActiveStorage resource's variant, based on viewport size. I'm trying to ensure that the views use the correct variants in the specs as well, but am running into `NoMethodError` problems.

### Breakdown

For example, with the following view partial:

```html
<div>
  <%= image_tag @post.image.variant(:web).processed.url %>
</div>
```

And this spec:

```rb
feature 'Posts', type: :feature do
  fixtures :posts, :users

  scenario 'Accessing a public post via ID' do
    visit post_path(posts(:one).id)
    expect(page).to have_css("#post-#{posts(:one).id}")
  end
end
```

And these fixtures (defined as per [the official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures)):

`posts.yml`:

```yaml
one:
  user: rafael
  filter: gotham
  private: false
  caption: This is a beautiful fixture
```

`active_storage/attachments.yml`:

```yaml
one:
  name: image
  record: rafael (User)
  blob: one_blob
```

`active_storage/blobs.yml`:

```yaml
one_blob:
  <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: 'storage/brighton-pier.jpg', service_name: 'test' %>
```

The views fail to render with:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `processed' for nil:NilClass
```

This makes sense, because the fixtures do not have variants defined.

#### Edit #1

The `Post` model has a set of predefined variants:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :web, resize_to_fill: [1200, 1200, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :opengraph, resize_to_fill: [200, 630, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :twitter, resize_to_fill: [1024, 512, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :mobile, resize_to_fill: [600, 600, { crop: :attention }]
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_fill: [100, 100, { crop: :attention }]
  end

  ...
end
```

### Question

How do I add variants to my ActiveStorage fixtures?

Comment: Can you add the definition of the ‘web’ variant? 

Also, do you mean to use “processed” in the image_tag - if you use the representation_url instead (default if you leave off ‘.processed.url’) it’ll generate as needed rather than inline as the image_tag is evaluated (or you can generate in a background job)

Comment: @nikz sure. I've updated the question with the model definition for `Post`. I want to use `.processed` because, as I understand it, it will use an existing variant from storage if it can be found, otherwise resorting to at-render time generation. This is intentional. I'm also using a helper route to return a CDN path instead of ActiveStorage's representation URL, which tends to be signed.

Comment: I have since moved away from fixtures in favour of factories (using FactoryBot), but I'll leave this question open for others.